# ecryptfs-mount-private is using login passphrase instead of mount passphrase on ubuntu 15.04

Tags: ubuntu, ecryptfs

When I used `ecryptfs-setup-private` on `ubuntu 15.04` I was asked for my login passphrase and to set a mount passphrase.

`~$ ecryptfs-setup-private -f
Enter your login passphrase [******]: 
Enter your mount passphrase [leave blank to generate one]: 
Enter your mount passphrase (again):`

I am assuming that the mount passphrase is going to be used as the actual passphrase for mounting the `Private` directory. But when I executed `ecryptfs-mount-private`, my mount passphrase returned an error while the user's system login passphrase succeeded. Anyone knows why? 

`~$ ecryptfs-mount-private
Enter your login passphrase:
Error: Unwrapping passphrase and inserting into the user session keyring failed [-5]
Info: Check the system log for more information from libecryptfs
ERROR: Your passphrase is incorrect
Enter your login passphrase:
Inserted auth tok with sig [****************] into the user session keyring`

PS: `ecryptfs-mount-private` used mount passphrase on another machine which has `ubuntu 14.04` installed so I am suspecting it has something to do with the ubuntu version.

Answer (score 5):

Because `ecryptfs-utils` package comes hard-coded with some assumptions, as:

- Your encrypted files are stored in `~/.Private` directory.
- Your decrypted data will be mounted in `~/Private` directory.
- Encryption keys are stored in `~/.ecryptfs`.
- Encryption key is just the mount passphrase wrapped (encoded) using your login passphrase, stored in `~/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase`.
- Uses `AES` with `16-byte` key cipher in encrypting data.

Thus, any time you try to mount the `eCryptfs` using `ecrypt-utils`, it asks for your login passphrase to decrypt the `wrapped-passphrase` file to get the actual mount passphrase, then uses it to mount the filesystem, and that is for a good reason.

It uses your default login passphrase so as for you not to have to remember two different passphrases, and, more importantly, to auto-mount it whenever you login, as it uses the passphrase you use to login to unlock your `Private` data, too.

If you leave the mount passphrase blank, it will be replaced with a pretty long random mount passphrase that is hard to guess, thus making your `.Private` directory more secure, as hackers that have access to it, but not your `wrapped-passphrase`, they would have to guess the very long mount random passphrase that you do not even have to memorize. The drawback of this technique is that losing the `wrapped-passphrase` file and you do not know the real mount passphrase, even you will be unable to access the decrypted data anymore.

In your case, your custom mount passphrase is wrapped with your login passphrase in `~/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase`, and to mount it you enter your login passphrase but the filesystem is really unlocked using the mount passphrase.

On other machines that does not have a `wrapped-passphrase` file, it uses the password you supply as the mount password directly, thus it works there.

To encrypt and decrypt data using custom passphrase, you have at least two options:

### Option 1: Using custom wrapping passphrase

Passing `--nopwcheck` to `ecryptfs-setup-private` while setting up private directory will not enforce entering the real login passphrase as the wrapping passphrase, thus issuing:

`$ ecryptfs-setup-private --nopwcheck`

will accept any passphrase you enter after `Enter your login passphrase [******]:`.

For the mount passphrase, you may enter the same password again, or leave it blank to generate you one, but if you are afraid of losing the `wrapped-passphrase` if it is auto-generated, you can issue:

`$ ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase ~/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase`

that will print you out the real mounting passphrase, that you can write down and keep in a safe place in case of emergency.

### Option 2: Using low-level mounting

Low-level mounting uses the mount passphrase directly. No wrapping/unwrapping included. Issuing

`# mount -t ecryptfs ~/.Private ~/Private`

will present you an interactive mounting. Choose options compatible with `ecryptfs-utils` unless you know what you are doing, and they are as follows:

`keytype`: `passphrase`, `passphrase`: enter real mount passphrase (not wrapping one), `cipher`: `AES`, `key bytes`: `16`, `plaintext paththrough`: `no`, `filename encryption`: `yes`, `fnek signature`: leave blank (default). Continue mounting and add signature to `sig-cache.txt` if asked to.

Even if the two directories were empty, this command only can effectively work for setting up new one in those custom directories, but it is advised when using it to setup a new encrypted directory not to use it with standard `Private` and `.Private` directories so as not to cause incompatibilities with standard `ecryptfs-utils` auto-mounting.

See also: [eCryptfs - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ECryptfs)